# java ftp nullpointer exception

Tags: java, networking, ftp, nullpointerexception, apache-commons

I have code to upload a file to a server.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.net.SocketException;

    public class FtpConnectDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException{
            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            client.connect("ftp.someserver.co.uk",21);
            boolean login = client.login("webmaster@someserver.co.uk",
                    "mypassword");


            String filename = "E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml";
            client.storeFile(filename, fis);
            client.logout();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

and when I run this code, it is giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FtpConnectDemo.main(FtpConnectDemo.java:22)
```

The username, password, servername are all right. What's wrong then?
I am able to connect to FTP using telnet. 
Any ideas?

#### EDIT 1

OK, now I am not getting the nullpointer exception, as I initialized `fis`. But my file is not uploaded yet; what might be the problem?

Comment: line 22 is fis.close() ? fis is null, so you can't call a method on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never instanciate your variable `fis`. I think that this is your problem here.

This cause two problems:

- You try to store `null` as a file, line 20. This is handled by the Apache FTP library you are using.
- `NullPointerException` line 22, when you try to call `close()`.

---

Also, other thing I'd like to point out: line 20, when you are calling `storeFile`. The path you are giving is a path pointing to a local file. I think you should put the remote file path in here.

The final code should look like this:

```
// ...

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml");

// ...

client.storeFile("engine.xml", fis);

// ...
```

Comment: thank you, it worked! Any idea about how to do the same thing using tftp?!

Comment: For TFTP, I'd say, use a TFTP library? AFAIK, this one only does FTP.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing

```
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
```

before `client.storeFile()`

Comment: thanks for that, I did it, but still the file is not getting uploaded, any idea?!

Comment: the string you pass to the client should be where you want to store it on the client (conversely the FileInputStream should come from the local filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `fis` cannot be anything other than `null` (you only initialise it with `null`), so the `NullPointerException` is natural when you try to execute `close()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The sendFile method on client.storeFile returns a boolean.  I would first check that value to see if it is failing or maybe just importing to somewhere you're not expecting.

The client also has a [getReplyCode](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#getReplyCode%28%29) and [getReplyString](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#getReplyString%28%29) methods which you could use to see what the server is up to.